# Text-rendering in chrome

Tags: css

How can we use text-rendering only for a particular class in css
    * {
    text-rendering:optimizelegibility;

}

Answer (score 1):

```
.classname{
       text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` is the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector). Unqualified, it matches all elements.

Use a class (or any other valid CSS) selector:

```css
/* match a class name */
.my-class { text-rendering: optimizelegibility; }

/* match an element ID */
#my-id { text-rendering: optimizelegibility; }

/* match all P elements inside any element with a class name */
.my-class P { text-rendering: optimizelegibility; }
```

See also:

- [CSS 3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)
- [text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering)